# Error add TextView

Tags: java, android

In XML file I create TextView. Than I want add to Activity from code

```html
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/letter_cell"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="1"
/>
```

MainActivity

```java
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View table_pattern = inflater.inflate(R.layout.letters_table, null);
TextView txt_row = (TextView) table_pattern.findViewById(R.id.letter_cell);

LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);

linLayout.addView(txt_row);
```

After run app I get some error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking an element from one view (`TextView` from `R.layout.letters_table`) and trying to add it to a `LinearLayout`. You have to either add the entire inflated view or create a `TextView` programatically. Views can only have one parent and will throw the exception you are seeing when you try to add to another view.

Answer (score 0):

The `txt_row` textView already has a parent because it's inside of `table_pattern`. You need to:

- Leave the textView alone in its own xml file, OR...
- Remove it from its parent first:

  ```
  table_pattern.removeView(txt_row);
  linLayout.addView(txt_row);
  ```

Both should work. Hope it helps!